# Celery workers to process the same queue, names?

Tags: python, django, celery

I already have a celery process running on a server using this command:

```
celery -A tasks worker -Q main_tasks -l INFO -n main_tasks
```

Can I use the same command to run a second worker consuming form the same queue on another server or would there be a conflict with the name below `-n`?

```
celery -A tasks worker -Q main_tasks -l INFO -n main_tasks
```

If so, can we make the name random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker) does note that the name should be unique per worker:

```
$ celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker1.%h
$ celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker2.%h
$ celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker3.%h
```